# In sequelize, how do I select records that match different values of multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

As an example, I have the following table:

```
A | B
------
1 | 2
1 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 3
2 | 4
3 | 3
```

I want to select all values in B that have the value 1 **AND** 2 in the  A Column. So in the above example I should get as a result (3,4) because only 3 and 4 have for column A the values 1 and 2.

How would I do this in sequelize?

This is what I tried:

```
 db.myModel.findAll({
    where: {
      A: whatImSearching
    },
    attributes: ['A', 'B']
  })
```

with `whatImSearching = [1,2]`

But that solution returns results where only one of the values match, i.e. I would get as a result (2,3,4). But I should only get (3,4).

Comment: `1 or 2` in the A Column or `1 and 2` in the A Column

Comment: out of curiosity, did you figure this out? I'm trying to do this the sequelize way as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This is how it can be done in SQL, like @daf mentioned in comments, something on similar lines can be implemented in Sequelize. I've kept this around as a reference*

You can use group by with conditional having like this

```
SELECT B 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY B
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN A IN(1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
```

**EDIT**

Assuming your have duplicate values. this should be better

```
SELECT B 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY B
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN A = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: Question is about using Sequelize, an ORM for NodeJS. Rolling your own SQL is not required -- and, imo, not a good idea if the ORM layer provides the functionality.

Comment: @daf you are right. I will keep this answer around as a reference only untill someone answers this in Sequelize

Comment: @daf - Definitely I wont say answer is not useful or not required. I have seen many looking for above scenarios in `SQL`

Comment: @Prdp: not saying the answer is bunk -- just not what the OP was looking for (:

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I'm not immediately seeing a pure Sequelize way to do this, however the below should get where you want with the small hit of bringing back some extra rows from the database.

Assuming that you're doing the query using a model like:

```
var model = sequelize.define('model', { 
    A: { type: Sequelize.TEXT }, 
    B: { type: Sequelize.TEXT }
}, {
    tableName: 'SomeTable',
    timestamps: false
})
```

you can do:

```
var search = [1,2];
model.findAll({
    where: { A: { '$in': search } },
    attributes: ['A', 'B']
}).then(function(instances) {
  var unwrapped = instances.map(function(i) { 
    return i.get();
  });
  var withCounts = unwrapped.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    var thisB = cur.B;
    var accItem = acc.filter(function(i) { 
      return i.B === thisB; 
    })[0];
    if (!accItem) {
      accItem = { B: thisB, count: 0 };
      acc.push(accItem);
    }
    accItem.count++;
  }, [])
  var hasAll = withCounts.filter(function(i) {
    return i.count === search.length;
  }).map(function(i) {
    return i.B;
  });
})
```

Comment: I think this would return 2,3,4 as b

Comment: I tried this before. But then I would also get values that only got one of the values in the array. In the above example I would also get the record 2 in column B. Record 2 in B has got the value 1 in column A but no value 2 in column A.